# Keep classnames with CSS loader or organize code in React?

Tags: reactjs, css-loader

How can I use my own class names when using CSS and Style loaders? I'm using React and i often get confused with all the class names and the related components. If it is not recommended to keep the class names, how can I organize my code in a manner that it don't get messy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal `classNames` and then import the relative `.css` file that has the style for those classes. Something like this:

`MyComponent.js`

```
...
import '/path/to/css/style.css'
...
render() {
  return(<div className="MyComponent">Hello</div>);
}
...
```

`style.css`

```
...
.MyComponent {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  ...
}
...
```

And this would work just fine, with this approach though you are in charge of naming your classes and making sure there are no collisions and everything is named properly (you can then follow BEM techinque or others as you prefer).

Otherwise there are other approaches that I am  not gonna explain into details because the relative docs are great and don't need any addition.

You can use [Css Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) or [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/). There is also [this article](https://m.alphasights.com/css-evolution-from-css-sass-bem-css-modules-to-styled-components-d4c1da3a659b) that has a good overview of these methods and can help you out make a final decision.